# rollover menu css3

Tags: css, menu, hover, transition, rollover

I've got a problem with rollover menu `css3`.
I need to create something like this:

[image]

I'm sitting on this for two days and I still have problems.
There is my progress (Upper right corner): 
http://dash.com.pl/CTP/index.html#

So, the problem is, I can't display my second ul while I set `position:absolute` to this.
I can't also set padding-bottom to first Ul.

Sure I made some mistakes, if someone could see what I did wrong, I would be grateful.

http://jsfiddle.net/SD58Z/800/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your css add

```
#language {overflow: hidden; }
```

And by the way pls, close your links before you close the div!,

```
<div> <a href="#"> Link</a></div>
```

Comment: @Lukas add the css from DreaminMedia Queretaro

Answer (score 0):

Hi you should close `<a>` tag inside the `div` and change html code like this:

```
<ul class="language" id="language">
     <li><div id="sve"><a href="#">svensk<div id="ico"><span></span></div></a></div>                
         <div id="uk"><a href="#">english</a></div>             
     </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Now I have something like this: http://dash.com.pl/CTP/index.html Do you know, how can I add a bottom padding for first li?

Comment: Now you need to do few css adjustment like: make li larger 100px, remove border from li and put it to ul and find a way to put text upper

Comment: Almost done: http://dash.com.pl/CTP/index.html I have last question for You. Can You tell me, how to do that after rolling over, content does not move down?

Comment: you can put the language roll-over menu in a wrapper div who`s height will be the height of roll over language menu when is rolled over

Comment: Ok, but now I have another problem. My second titles in language menu do not hide: http://dash.com.pl/CTP/index.html